# z-index qith jquery not working on rotated image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, css

JsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/E4s9k/

HTML:

```
<body>
<section id="pics" class="clearfix">
        <figure
            id="pic1"
            class="pictures"
        >
            <img
                alt="figure1"
                src="http://b-i.forbesimg.com/kellyclay/files/2013/12/glass.jpg"
                title="pic1"
            >
            <figcaption class="figuredetails">Fig1</figcaption>

        </figure>


        <figure
            id="pic2"
            class="pictures"
        >
            <img
                alt="figure2"
                src="http://glass-apps.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/google-glass1.jpg"
                title="pic2"
            >
            <figcaption class="figuredetails">Fig2</figcaption>

        </figure>
    </section>
    <section id="content">
    <p>hello</p>
    </section>
</body>
```

CSS:-

```
@CHARSET "UTF-8";

#pics{

    width:100%;
    padding: 50px 50px;
} 

.pictures{
    float: left;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}



.pictures img{
    width:100%;
    height:auto;



}

#pic1{

    -ms-transform: rotate(30deg); 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg); 
    transform: rotate(30deg);
    z-index: -1
} 


#pic2{
    position: absolute;
    -ms-transform: rotate(50deg); 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(50deg); 
    transform: rotate(50deg);
    /* z-index: -2; */

}

#content{
    clear: both;
}

.pictures > .figuredetails{
    color: red;
    padding-left: 20px;
}

.clearfix:after { 
   content: "."; 
   visibility: hidden; 
   display: block; 
   height: 0; 
   clear: both;
}
```

JQuery:

```
function pichoverfunc() {
    $(this).css({"z-index":10});
}

function pichoverfuncO() {
    $(this).css({"z-index":-10});
}


$(document).ready(

        $("#pic2").hover(pichoverfunc, pichoverfuncO)
        );
```

**I'm trying to do something like this:-**

1. Show 2 rotated images on the top of each other.
2. When hovered above any image (even near its egde), that image should come to the front and the one that is in front should go to back
3. This is a future things (in my to-do list) - Use more than 2 images to achieve the same functionality as in step 2.

**The  problem:**
1. I cant hover on the second image
2. (This is linked to the requirement 3 above) If there are more than 2 images, then, how should I choose z-index for each image that is in the back?

**What I've tried:-**

1. I've used the Dev tools in chrome to inspect the `#pic2` but, I still cant select it.

As I'm new to HTML, CSS, and Jquery, Any help would be great.

Answer (score 0):

You dont need to use Jquery to change an element on hover. CSS has this functionality built in, take a look at this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp). As you can see you can set a css class or id to change on hover. So for instance:

```
#pic2{
    position: absolute;
    -ms-transform: rotate(50deg); 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(50deg); 
    transform: rotate(50deg);
    /* z-index: -2; */

}
```

Then below that you could put somthing like this:

```
#pic2:hover{
z-index:10;
}
```

This should change the z-index of pic2 on hover with only CSS, also if you want to do this with many images try using a class instead of an id or maybe just do it using tag name. So for instance assign class="img-hover" to all the images youd like. Then in your css put:

```
.img-hover:hover{
z-index:10;
}
```

or if you want to just apply the hover to all img tags youd just put:

```
img:hover{
...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The root cause why your script does not work is probably the fact that:

> z-index will only work on an element whose position property has been explicitly set to absolute, fixed, or relative.

Read more on the z-index: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/15/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/

When it comes to your JSFiddle, I cleaned it up a bit and simplified it a bit - http://jsfiddle.net/E4s9k/

HTML:

```
<body>
 <img
     id="pic1"
     alt="figure1"
     src="http://b-i.forbesimg.com/kellyclay/files/2013/12/glass.jpg"
     title="pic1"
 >
 <img
     id="pic2"
     alt="figure2"
     src="http://glass-apps.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/google-glass1.jpg"
     title="pic2"
 >
</body>
```

JS:

```
function handlerIn() {
    $('img').css({"z-index": -10}); //Push all images back
    $(this).css({"z-index": 10}); //Bring our target to front
}

function handlerOut() {
    $('img').css({"z-index": 10}); //Bring all our images to front
    $(this).css({"z-index": -10}); //Push target back
}

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("img").hover(handlerIn, handlerOut);
});
```

CSS:

```
img {
    position: relative;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    box-shadow: 10px 10px 5px #888888;
}

#pic1{
    -ms-transform: rotate(30deg); 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(30deg); 
    transform: rotate(30deg);
} 

#pic2{
    -ms-transform: rotate(50deg); 
    -webkit-transform: rotate(50deg); 
    transform: rotate(50deg);   
}
```